# React query error boundaries: how to give users different options depending on whether they are seeing the component for the second time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, react-query, react-error-boundary

I'm trying to improve error handling in my app that uses `react-query`.

I have an `<ErrorBoundary>` component for my authenticated user router:

```
<ErrorBoundaryRoot errorMessage="auth error">
  <PracticeTypeContextProvider>
    <IonReactRouter>
       ... myRoutesAndStuff
```

The component wrapper looks like this:

```
import { ErrorBoundary } from 'react-error-boundary';

const ErrorBoundaryRoot: React.VFC<MyProps> = ({ children, errorMessage }: MyProps) => {
  const { reset } = useQueryErrorResetBoundary();

  return (
    <ErrorBoundary
      onReset={reset}
      fallbackRender={({ resetErrorBoundary }) => (
        <PageError errorMessage={errorMessage} resetErrorBoundary={resetErrorBoundary} />
      )}
    >
      <Suspense fallback={<LoadingApp />}>
        { children }
      </Suspense>
    </ErrorBoundary>
  );
};
```

This correctly catches the errors, great!

Now, I wanted to show users one of two buttons:

- If it is the first time seeing the error boundary, `<ButtonInvalidateAuthQueries>`, so that I can try to reset the app without logging the user out.
- But, if that fails, I want to show the user a different button, `<ButtonResetApp>`, that resets all queries and logs the user out.

I set up my `<PageError>` component like this:

```
const PageError: React.VFC<MyProps> = ({ errorMessage, resetErrorBoundary }: MyProps) => {
  const [alreadyTriedItOnce, setAlreadyTriedItOnce] = useState(false);
  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonContent>
        <>
          { alreadyTriedItOnce ? (
            <ButtonResetApp platform={platform} resetErrorBoundary={resetErrorBoundary} />
          ) : (
            <ButtonInvalidateAuthQueries
              setAlreadyTriedItOnce={setAlreadyTriedItOnce}
              resetErrorBoundary={resetErrorBoundary}
            />
          )}
        </>
        )}
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
};
```

And the invalidate button:

```
const ButtonInvalidateAuthQueries: React.VFC<MyProps> = (
  { setAlreadyTriedItOnce, resetErrorBoundary }: MyProps,
) => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  return (
    <IonButton
      onClick={() => {
        queryClient.invalidateQueries(queryKeyInvalidateAllAuthQueries);
        resetErrorBoundary();
        setAlreadyTriedItOnce(true);
      }}
    >
      Reset auth queries
    </IonButton>
  );
};
```

However, this doesn't work, because when the user clicks `<ButtonInvalidateAuthQueries>`, then all the auth components get re-rendered, including the error boundary, so if the error boundary is shown again, the `alreadyTriedItOnce` state is initialized to false.

So my question is: is there some clever way to tell if `<ButtonInvalidateAuthQueries>` has failed, and if so, show `<ButtonResetApp>` instead?

As a workaround, I can show both buttons, and give users the instruction "click this one first, and if that doesn't work, click the other one," but I feel like as a programmer it's my job to give users the best option at any given time.

Comment: Please post the code of the `ErrorBoundary`, it's much more relevant here. It is where you will need to put the `alreadyTriedItOnce` state (or maybe more generically, a count of occurred errors)

Comment: @Bergi Ok, I posted the full code for the error boundary.

Comment: I didn't mean the `ErrorBoundaryRoot`, I mean the code of the `<ErrorBoundary>` itself

Comment: @Bergi Oops, sorry.  Updated again.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I had not realised there is a [*react-error-boundary* package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-error-boundary). It doesn't really seem up to the task - maybe using [`onError`](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-error-boundary#onerror)? - but I'd recommend just writing your own error boundary that counts the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this based on the comments from Bergi by using Context.

First, I created a simple context to store a boolean useState:

```
import React from 'react';
import useStateBoolean from '../utils/hooks/useStateBoolean';

const ErrorTriedAlreadyContext = React.createContext(false);
const ErrorTriedAlreadySetContext = React.createContext(
  {} as React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>,
);

interface MyProps {
  children: JSX.Element,
}

export const ErrorTriedAlreadyContextProvider: React.VFC<MyProps> = ({ children }: MyProps) => {
  const [triedAlready, setTriedAlready] = useStateBoolean();

  return (
    <ErrorTriedAlreadyContext.Provider value={triedAlready}>
      <ErrorTriedAlreadySetContext.Provider value={setTriedAlready}>
        {children}
      </ErrorTriedAlreadySetContext.Provider>
    </ErrorTriedAlreadyContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useErrorAlreadyTriedContext = (): [
  boolean, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>,
] => {
  const triedAlready = React.useContext(ErrorTriedAlreadyContext);
  const setTriedAlready = React.useContext(ErrorTriedAlreadySetContext);

  if (!setTriedAlready) {
    throw new Error('The ErrorTriedAlreadyProvider is missing.');
  }

  return [triedAlready, setTriedAlready];
};
```

Then, I created a new ErrorBoundary:

```
const ErrorBoundaryAuth: React.VFC<MyProps> = ({ children }: MyProps) => {
  const { reset } = useQueryErrorResetBoundary();

  return (
    <ErrorTriedAlreadyContextProvider>
      <ErrorBoundary
        onReset={reset}
        fallbackRender={({ resetErrorBoundary }) => (
          <PageError
            errorMessage={t({ id: 'error.auth_router_query_error', message: 'Temporary app error' })}
            allowAuthReset
            resetErrorBoundary={resetErrorBoundary}
          />
        )}
      >
        <Suspense fallback={<LoadingApp />}>
          { children }
        </Suspense>
      </ErrorBoundary>
    </ErrorTriedAlreadyContextProvider>
  );
};
```

I added it to my router:

```
  return (
    <ErrorBoundaryAuth>
      <PracticeTypeContextProvider>
        <IonReactRouter>
```

And my button:

```
const ButtonInvalidateAuthQueries: React.VFC<MyProps> = (
  { resetErrorBoundary }: MyProps,
) => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  const [, setAlreadyTried] = useErrorAlreadyTriedContext();
  return (
    <>
      <IonButton
        onClick={() => {
          queryClient.invalidateQueries(queryKeyInvalidateAllNonCookieQueries);
          if (resetErrorBoundary) {
            resetErrorBoundary();
          }
          // The context may not always be available.
          if (setAlreadyTried) {
            setAlreadyTried(true);
          }
        }}
      >
        <IonIcon icon={sync} slot="start" />
        <Trans id="button.reset_queries">Try again</Trans>
      </IonButton>
    </>
  );
};
```

And now it works!